# Could not catch exceptions created from errors

Tags: php, exception

I am running PHP 5.4.12 on Ubuntu 12.10.

I am using an error handler to turn PHP errors into exceptions so I can handle them. However, I am finding that while I can turn errors into exceptions, there doesn't really seem to be a way to catch the exception at all.

Here's some simple demonstration code:

```
<?php 
class CErrorException extends Exception {}

function handleError($level, $message, $file, $line){

    if( error_reporting() != 0){
        throw new CErrorException($message, $level);
    }
}

function handleException(Exception $exception){
    var_dump('Exception handled at global level');
}

set_error_handler('handleError');

set_exception_handler('handleException');

try {
    require_once('non\existent\file'); //Will generate an error and cause an exception to be thrown.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump("let's deal with the exception");
}
```

Unfortunately, in this case, I can never catch the exception that is thrown, which makes it hard to recover from issues caused by using `require_once` on a non existent or unreadable file.

I get these 2 errors:

```
Warning: Uncaught exception 'CErrorException' with message 'require_once(non\existent\file): failed to open stream: Invalid argument' in /work/test.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /work/test.php(20): handleError(2, 'require_once(no...', '/work/test.php', 20, Array) #1 /work/test.php(20): require_once() #2 {main} thrown in /work/test.php on line 7

Fatal error: main(): Failed opening required 'non\existent\file'
```

Is there simply no way to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

Not all errors are processable with an error handler. A fatal error in PHP core will stop processing of further instructions, which include processing your error handler. From the documentation of [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/set-error-handler):

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

Comment: But in his output you can see that the error was handled since the exception was created. The question was "why is this exception not catchable?" and not "why is this error unhandlable?"

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois Hmm you are right... I have no explanation for that. On PHP 5.3.10 in ubuntu 12.04 the result is different though: `PHP Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required 'non\existent\file' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/bla on line 20` (line 20 is the `require_once` line)